# Is there an online Encyclopedia of Photographic Methods/Techniques, better than that in Wikipedia?

Tags: technique, web

Looking for a listing photographic methods/techniques just like [this one on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Photographic_techniques), but possibly better, any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @blunders — welcome to the site. Your link ended up not working. The question here seems quite broad in any case — maybe something we can't really answer. Are you looking for an actual book (or web site) that acts as a reference?

Comment: +1 @mattdm: Fixed the link, and yes, it would need to be online. Also, agree that references are broad in nature, but as a resource is well defined I believe. If you have any additional questions, just let me know. Cheers!

Comment: +1 @mattdm: wow, my bad, fixed and CHECKED it ...google the same query on google and saw a page I'd visited before (this page is already ranking better in google than the page I'm linking to at Wikipedia, odd) here's the google search, http://www.google.com/search?q=Photographic+Methods%2FTechniques

Comment: I'll be surprised if anything else online beats that Wikipedia listing. You could always turn to paper.... http://www.focalpress.com/books/photography/the_focal_encyclopedia_of_photography.aspx

Comment: Hey, give us time, we just got started less than a year ago!

Comment: JoanneC: ha. I mean, we could _start_ such a question as a community wiki, but I'm not sure of the value. @blunders, I think we're stronger here on questions _about_ a specific technique....

Comment: There's a [list here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tags) but it's broader than just techniques :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no, there does not appear to be a reference of this nature online.

Answer (score 2):

there is always [Digital Photography school](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/)

Comment: I recommend this website. Just find yourself a decent blog or forum and start following it on a day by day basis.

Comment: But it's not really encyclopedia-like. It's more like a magazine.

Answer (score 1):

Online? Well not quite yet but hopefully this site will get there after a few years.

In the mean time The Focal Encyclopedia of Photography is a good read.

References.
[Book review](http://blogcritics.org/books/article/book-review-the-focal-encyclopedia-of/)
[Amazon books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240807405)
[Google Books](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=VYyldcYfq3MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=focal%20encyclopedia%20of%20photography&source=bl&ots=sZm8EvPk8S&sig=4o2s3QXXrjqbS0QOK6Kuo8APzec&hl=en&ei=SN2nTYC-OMKqhAfdr_HYCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

There are some in-depth articles on [DPanswers](http://dpanswers.com/content/essays.php) on topics such as

- exposure triangle
- aperture and f/stop
- depth of field
- metering and zone system
- color spaces
- testing camera autofocus
- Canon and Nikon flash primers
- GPS and geotagging

These tend towards being a bit technical in nature.  Not sure if this is useful to the OP, but it's a good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

I was just recommended this site by my photography teacher. I have never used it myself
[Digital Photography BestFlow](http://www.dpbestflow.org/)